# Проблема с передачей данных массивом POST

Tags: post, php

Есть список строк из таблицы в форме html, хочу передать данные, которые изменил пользователь, POST запросом. соответственно к каждой строке из 5 полей прилагается чекбокс.

Все работает, но код работает так что в массив заносятся все строки таблицы что переполняет размер POST запроса и вообще так, по-моему, не делается. Как правильно переделать? чтобы в массив заносились конечно только данные с установленным чекбоксом?

примерный код выглядит так:

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="form1">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="array_checkbox[$id]" id="ch_$id"></td>
<td><input onchange="set_checkbox('$id')" name="array_data[$id][field1_name]" value=$field1" ></td>
<td><input  onchange="set_checkbox('$id')"  name="array_data[$id][field2_name]" value="$field2"></td>
<td colspan="5"><textarea onchange="set_checkbox('$id')" name="array_data[$id][field3_name]">$field3</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="form_action[][1]" value="Действие1">
        <input type="submit" name="form_action[][2]" value="Действие2">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Обновление**

"Переполняет" - это когда я делаю `var_export($_POST);` выводится лишь часть данных, обрезает где-то на половине из 500 строк, согласен в настройках можно увеличить количество допустимых массивов к передаче(общий размер 200М), но мне кажется просто неправильно кучу данных без фильтра пихать в пост-строку. Сейчас 500 строк, через год будет 5000, опять какие-то проблемы возникнут. Возможно есть какой-то нормальный способ отфильтровать предварительно данные с помощью формы?

Comment: `var_export($_POST)` вы в каком веке живете? в каменном?

Comment: [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) для 21 века

Answer (score 1):

Хм... а что значит "переполняет"? POST может быть хоть каким большим, главное все настроить. Для текста вам даже стандартных настроек апача с php должно хватить.

А если хотите отправлять только по чекбоксу - может быть стоит убрать форму и отправлять через JS? Т.е. пробегаете по данным - если флажок стоит, значит добавляете в отправляемые.

Comment: Можно пример, где почитать как это сделать через js без формы?